# How to decrease query execution time on a db with 20 million records | Rails, Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails app with Postgres db. It has 20 million records. Most of the queries use ILIKE. I have created a triagram index on one of the columns.

Before adding the triagram index, the query execution time was ~200s to ~300s (seconds not ms)

After creating the triagram index, the query execution time came down to ~30s.

How can I reduce the execution time to milliseconds?

Also are there any good practices/suggestions when dealing with a database  this huge?

Thanks in advance :)

Ref : [Faster PostgreSQL Searches with Trigrams](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2016/07/12/how-to-make-text-searches-in-postgresql-faster-with-trigram-similarity)

Edit: 'Explain Analyze' on one of the queries

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "listings" WHERE (categories ilike '%store%');

                        QUERY PLAN        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=716850.70..716850.71 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=199354.861..199354.861 rows=1 loops=1)
 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on listings  (cost=3795.12..715827.76 rows=409177 width=0) (actual time=378.374..199005.008 rows=691941 loops=1)
     Recheck Cond: ((categories)::text ~~* '%store%'::text)
     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 7302878
     Heap Blocks: exact=33686 lossy=448936
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on listings_on_categories_idx  (cost=0.00..3692.82 rows=409177 width=0) (actual time=367.931..367.931 rows=692449 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((categories)::text ~~* '%store%'::text)
 Planning time: 1.345 ms
 Execution time: 199355.260 ms
 (9 rows)
```

Comment: "Most of the queries use ILIKE", so you're talking about more than one query. How do these queries look like? How do the tables look like? Have you already done an `explain analyze` on one of the queries?

Comment: Maybe only a good dedicated external search engine can help, but to be able to tell details, I'd have to see `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Edited the question to inlcude the 'Explain Analyze'

Comment: Heap blocks reports 448936 lossy vs 33686 exact blocks. So increasing `work_mem` to about 15 to 20 times the current value could avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index scan itself is fast (0.3 seconds), but the trigram index finds more than half a million potential matches. All of these rows have to be checked if they actually match the pattern, which is where the time is spent.

For longer strings or strings with less common letters the performance should be considerably better. Is it a solution for you to impose a lower bound on the length of the search string?

Other than that, maybe the only solution is to use an external text search software.

Comment: Thank you. I will probably go with ElasticSearch or Sunspot. If I may ask, which one do your prefer?

Comment: I have no experience with either.

Comment: hey , gotta say, i am still in problem , but the thing i increase the size of search parameter , if the parameter length is 1 , i added the another two zeros and , it makes bit faster, which is wrong but i don't expect my user to type only one number , i also short the result.